# Portfolio Optimization Problem

Tags: portfolio-optimization

I have the following expression for which I wish to find the $\vec{w}$ which minimizes it:

$$
L = \frac{\vec{w}^TA\vec{w}}{\vec{w}^TB\vec{w}} - \lambda(\vec{w}^T\vec{1} - 1)
$$

The partial derivates with respect to $\vec{w}$ and $\lambda$ are as follows

\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{w}} &= \frac{2(\vec{w}^TB\vec{w})A\vec{w}-2(\vec{w}^TA\vec{w})B\vec{w}}{(\vec{w}^TB\vec{w})^2} - \lambda \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} &= -\vec{w}^T\vec{1} + 1
\end{align*}

But I'm having a hard time simplifying these to get the minimizing value of $\vec{w}$. Any insights?

Comment: Would you mind explaining what A and B stands for? Thanks

Comment: They are both nxn matrices, and $\vec{w}$ is an nx1 vector

Comment: If you want more detail than that:
$$A = \Sigma - \sigma_D^2; B = \sigma_D1\sigma_D - \sigma_D^2$$
where $\Sigma = $ Covariance matrix of assets, $\sigma_D = $ diagonal matrix showing each asset's standard deviations (so $\sigma_D^2$ is the same but with variances), and the $1$ matrix is simply an nxn matrix filled with ones. $A$ is therefore essentially a matrix filled with the covariances between each asset but with zeros along the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the $\vec w^TB\vec w$ in the denominator, **you have to solve this problem numerically**, either as a direct minimization with a constraint, or by finding the roots of the two Lagrangian equations after taking partial derivatives.

- Direct minimization with linear equality constraint

$$
min_\vec{w} \left(\frac{\vec{w}^TA\vec{w}}{\vec{w}^TB\vec{w}}\right) \quad s.t. \quad\vec{w}^T \vec{1}-1 = 0.
$$
In Python this can be done e.g. using *scipy.optimize.minimize* with equality constraint argument specified.

- Alternatively, solve the lagrangian system of equations

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \vec{w}} = 0 \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda} = 0,
$$
by finding the vector $\vec{w}$ and the value of $\lambda$ that solves the two equations (root finding).
In Python this can be done using *scipy.optimize.root.*